# Calling a function in every repeat by using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following relationship: Categories <---> Products (with a 1-N cardinality)

This is the *ng-repeat* directive in the html table

```
<tr ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <td>{{category.name}}</td>
    <td>{{products[category.id]}}</td>
</tr>
```

So what I need to do is when every time the repeat list a category, this category will be send immediately to the *getAllProductsByCategory()* function and then the $http service will get all the products that belong to this specific category.

I tried to use the *ng-init* directive in order to execute the function but I think it's not the correct way to use it. Is there a better way to do it?

```
<tr ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-init="getAllProductsByCategory(category)">
    <td>{{category.name}}</td>
    <td>{{products[category.id]}}</td>
</tr>
```

And this is the function that will get all the products by category

```
$scope.getAllProductsByCategory = function(category){
$http("getAlProductsByCategory"+category.id){
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.products[category.id] = data;
    })
    .error(function (data, status, header, config){
        $log.error("Error");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to split an array in the controller in order to pass every object to the getAllProductsByCategory(category)

I don't recommend using `ng-init` to make calls to asynchronous APIs. In a model-view-whatever architechure, the model should drive the view. The view should not drive the model. The view can collect user input events for the controller. The controller can then use those events to update the model, using asynchronous APIs if necessary.

In this case the list of categories probably came from an asynch API, then the products for each category need to come from an asynch API. This can accomplished be [chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises).

First create a categories promise:

```
var categoriesPromise = $http.get(categoriesUrl)
  .then(function (response) {
    var categories = response.data;
    $scope.categories = categories;
    //return to chain categories
    return categories;
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("ERROR: ", error.status);
    //throw to chain rejection
    throw error;
});
```

Now chain from that promise:

```
$scope.products = {};

var productsPromise = categoriesPromise.then(function(categories) {
    var promiseHash = {};
    categories.foreach(function(c) {
        promiseHash[c.id] = getProductsByCategory(c)
          .then(function(products) {
             $scope.products[c.id] = products;
             //return data for chaining
             return products;
        });
    });
    //return $q.all promise for chaining
    return $q.all(promiseHash);
});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)
- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - $q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed question but I have a little problem with the second promise, I don't know where is supposed to be placed the "getAlProductsByCategory"+category.id" request. As you know I need to make a call to an async API. I have the following error https://k60.kn3.net/8/1/D/2/0/8/4BB.png Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: hi, did you see the question above?

Comment: Creating the `getProductsByCategory` function is an execise left for the reader. Follow the example of the $http call for the `categoriesPromise`. Use the `.then` and `.catch` methods. **Avoid** using the `.success` and `.error` methods as they **ignore return values** and are deprecated and have been removed from AngularJS 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

ng-init will be execute only once at the beginning not for every category.
I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <td>{{category.name}}</td>
    <td>{{products[category.id]}}</td>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         getAllProductsByCategory({{category}});
    </script>
</tr>
```

but there are easier ways to do this, instead of calling once for each category, which is bad from a performance point of view, like creating an array of categories and calling them only once in the controller having them ready for whatever you want to use them.

Comment: Thanks man, but I don't know how to split an array in the controller in order to pass every object to the getAllProductsByCategory(category). Please share with me any related example.

Comment: Isn't categories already an array? Or at least an enumerable where you can call something for each element in it, with something like lodash https://lodash.com/ but my point was that you should call a function which returns all the products all at once instead of creating a post for each category and get the overhead from it. Imagine you have 2000 categories. Are you really gonna make 2000 calls to the server?

Comment: Please see this code http://plnkr.co/edit/KMz09pJORmtflcl948kU?p=preview

Comment: @wilson Kinds like this http://plnkr.co/edit/e7NuAOYEPoe1E80YPMpA?p=preview all changes in script.js, note that it's sort of pseudo code, not meant to be working "as is" just to give you an idea of what i meant.

Comment: Okay, I'll see what happens I really appreciate your help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Functions inside `<script>` tags execute on global scope, not on the AngularJS framework scope.

Comment: @georgeawg yeah, you're right, he can make it global though, but i was trying to tell him not to do that anyway, so i stand by my answer (the second part anyway).

Comment: The statement that the `ng-init` will only execute once not for every category is incorrect. The `ng-repeat` directive has higher priority than `ng-init`. 'ng-init` will execute once for every category on the child scope creatied for each category. It is a useful for nested `ng-repeat` direcitves. It is not recommended for starting asynchronous API calls.